# How to get a UIViewController with buttons to work every time it loads, not every second time it loads

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, viewdidload

When loading controller two from the press of a button in controller one, the buttons in controller two work.

If the back (navigation bar) button is pressed in controller two to load controller one and then the button to load controller two is pressed again, the buttons in controller two don't work.

They work on the next attempt and every second attempt.

It's possibly something to do with the 'if statement' but I need a solution so the buttons open and close as intended.

// Controller one

```
@objc func demoButtonTap()
{
    let demoController = DemoController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(demoController, animated: true)
}
```

// Controller two

```
@objc func demo1ButtonTap()
{
    if demoTextView1.isHidden == false
    {
        demoTextView1.isHidden = true
    }
    else
    {
        demoTextView1.isHidden = false
    }
    demoTextView2.isHidden = true
}

@objc func demo2ButtonTap()
{        
    if demoTextView2.isHidden == false
    {
        demoTextView2.isHidden = true
    }
    else
    {
        demoTextView2.isHidden = false
    }
    demoTextView1.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize your code

```swift
@objc func demo1ButtonTap()
{
    demoTextView1.isHidden = !demoTextView1.isHidden
    demoTextView2.isHidden = !demoTextView1.isHidden
}

@objc func demo2ButtonTap()
{        
    demoTextView2.isHidden = !demoTextView2.isHidden
    demoTextView1.isHidden = !demoTextView2.isHidden
}
```

Comment: There are more than two buttons and if the same button is pressed again then it closes all open views

Answer (score 0):

I just built a quick project based on the information you provide out of curiosity, and everything works normally. My guess is that the second view controller is not released when it's popped from the navigation stack because there's a strong reference somewhere in its code.

In the second view controller implement the `deinit` and see if it's called when you're tapping on the Back button:

```swift
deinit {
    print("Did call DEINIT in Second View Controller!")
}
```

If you don't see the above message then there's something not released when going back, so go through all your properties, etc and make sure that there's not any strong reference. Especially check for strong references to the first VC. Use `deinit` to make nil whatever you think the root of your problem is.

If the above doesn't help you towards the solution, then you should share more information so we have a better understanding on how you setup and use everything.

Finally, instead of this:

```swift
if demoTextView1.isHidden == false
{
    demoTextView1.isHidden = true
}
else
{
    demoTextView1.isHidden = false
}
```

you can write this:

```swift
demoTextView1.isHidden = !demoTextView1.isHidden
```

Comment: I added deinit {
    print("Did call DEINIT in Second View Controller!")
} in the class of the second controller and the message printed when I pressed the back button. The if statement makes it easier to control many other items in the view. I'm not sure what other code I could share that would be relevant.